# Supporting Multiple Screens in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, screen, resolution

I have developed an android app and its working fine in my mobile of resolution `240*320`.But if I install in another mobile some like `240*400,480*800`, etc all the view components are changing according to the screen resolution.
I also created a sub folders under the res like `layout-smal`l,`layout-large`,`layout-xlarge` this procedure is also working according to the screen resolution the xml files are been read by particular folder.But this is not working on a `240*400,240*432`,etc.., these type of screen resolutions are not supporting by the above procedure 
What should i do for achieving all the view components to be look same for all screen sizes.
Thank you

Comment: You have to check out this : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: i have read that many times and implemented according to that but read my question properly.

Comment: this is really not an easy thing to do. you should read official documentation about it and watch the videos in google IO

Answer (score 1):

This stuff is hard. You may have read the documentation, but you haven't understood it.

Basically, you have to distinguish two important things.

1. Layouts (XML) are determined by the dp size of the device. Forget about 'resolution' and just think about device independent pixels (dp). The dp size of a device is roughly equal to its size in inches, if it had 160 dots per inch. So a 10" tablet is about 8"x160=1280 dp long, while a 4" phone is about 3"x160=480 dp long. Approximately.
2. Drawables (PNG and JPG) are determined by the pixel resolution of the device. To produce the identical icon on a device that is 320 dpi and for one that is 160 dpi you need twice as many pixels. A 64x64 icon on the first is only 32x32 on the second.

So you need to produce a range of XML files (layout or dimen) that scale according to the desired dp size and put them in folders with names like sw600dp (shortest width 600 dp) and sw320dp. (Search SO or the web for sw600dp and you'll find lots to read).

And you need to produce a range of PNG or JPG files that scale according to the pixel resolution and put them in folders with names like mdpi and hdpi (search for that too).

Simple enough, but hard to do well in practice. We can only hope that eventually Android will fix this mess but for now this is what we have.

Answer (score 1):

First off, stop using the term resolution. That term is ambiguous.

In Android, one could easily have a phone with a small screen with very high pixel density and a large tablet screen with very low pixel density, and the so-called resulting resolution on both devices could still end up being equal.

> i have read that many times and implemented according to that but read
>   my question properly. –  user3851899 3 hours ago

I'm sorry, but believe us, we've parsed your question very thoroughly.
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

You've mentioned the term "resolution" five times and yet in the document you've read many times, below is the only part where resolution is even mentioned, and even then, it's to tell us that you should "not directly work with resolution".

> Resolution
>
> The total number of physical pixels on a screen. **When adding support for multiple screens, applications do not work
>   directly with resolution;** applications should be concerned only with
>   screen size and density, as specified by the generalized size and
>   density groups.

Furthermore, can you count the term **density** is mentioned in that document. It's mentioned **171 times**! The fact is, you've missed the main key take away concept from that document.

The term resolution is not very useful for Android development. The concept of size is important for a large background image taking the entire width or the entire height of the screen and it's important for layout issues that take into account the entire height of the screen or the entire width of the screen, but it's not very important otherwise. And what's really important for developing on multiple screens (aside from the scaling font size) is really the **density** of the screen.

So I implore you, please read that [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) again. Hopefully, you'll begin to understand it, now that I've reset some of your assumptions.